# SQLite LIKE query with "?"

Tags: sqlite, sql-like

I have a piece of code that wants to find the year of movies that match words given in the command line

The following code works for finding movies that match the string

```
query = "SELECT m.year FROM movie m WHERE m.title = ?"
cur.execute(query, (sys.argv[1], ))
```

However, this only works for strings that exactly match the title, I want to find all movies with the substring in the name, but the following query doesn't work.

```
query = "SELECT m.year FROM movie m WHERE m.title like %?%"
cur.execute(query, (sys.argv[1],))
```

I also tried the following code that I don't think is right either

```
query = "SELECT m.year FROM movie m WHERE m.title like %" + sys.argv[1] + "%"
cur.execute(query)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use the syntax

expression [NOT] IN (value_list|subquery);

*Example:*

```
SELECT
    TrackId,
    Name,
    Mediatypeid
FROM
    Tracks
WHERE
    MediaTypeId IN (1, 2)
ORDER BY
    Name ASC;
```

In your case it should be:

```
paramList = [sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2]]

query = "SELECT m.year FROM movie m WHERE m.title IN paramList"
```